# Sometimes [shift] happens... to need a re-tagging

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I don't think [shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shift) (16 followers, 666 *(uh-oh)* questions) needs a burnination, but yesterday I caught [a tag edit that tried to expand the scope](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18358855) to cover

- the already existing [bit-shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-shift), as well as
- the more common [Perl-like shuffling a list to the left](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html).

A quick look at the first 30 questions shows me two actually discussing the keyboard (retag to [shift-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shift-key)? We already have [alt-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alt-key) and [windows-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-key) although neither [control-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/control-key) nor [apple-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-key)), four discussing [bit-shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-shift), and most of the rest various forms of rotating array elements, and inevitably half-a-dozen cases of tag abuse for visually shifting things on screen.

So, I think we need to do a bit of re-tagging, and rename the [shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shift) tag to something that explicitly indicates it is for shifting collections, but [collection-shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collection-shift) seems a bit unwieldy to me.

Comment: The wiki of [tag:shift] is ... inappropriate, currently. Can you expand on what you think the tag should be used for?

Comment: And how about shifting gears in Your car? -:)

Comment: @Skipper Then Shift would get applied to all the "I'm learning object oriented programming and need to make a car object..." type questions ;D

Comment: Is "shifting collections" a concept that meets the criteria of a tag anyways?

Comment: That tag wiki edit should be rolled back IMO.

Comment: "discussing the keyboard" UL and even SU deem to have a tag specific for the shift key. The shift key (and any key) is just a code sent by the physical keyboard to the kernel to be interpreted. Unless you are programming for a kernel (or a very low level userspace program, like Xorg) you don't care what the shift key is, you deal with it like any keyboard key.

Comment: I rolled it back. Edits should never add more meanings to an existing tag

Comment: The person that made the edit to that tag certainly engaged in "shifty" behavior.

Comment: @Machavity Can you rollback the Excerpt too as that is still talking about bit-shifts.

Comment: @KenY-N Rolled back excerpt

Comment: Perl's `shift` is more commonly known as a 'pop' operation, often seen with queues or stacks.

Comment: See my taxonomy at [**Disambiguate the \[shift\] tag, it's totally overloaded**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368057/disambiguate-the-shift-tag-its-totally-overloaded), where I enumerated different meanings of "shift" on SO and came up with at least eight. Let's move the discussion there, since this question does not adequately reflect the possible meanings.

Answer (score 2):

[shift] certainly is a mess and needs a (long) bulleted list if we're even to keep so many meanings under one tag roof, but you misunderstood that [tag edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18358855), it was not just about bit-arrays, you missed the part **shifting of values across a sequence of fields**, such as shifting of bits in a bit-array.

"shifting of values across a sequence of fields" could equally be [vectorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vectorization) (Series operations spanning multiple indices e.g. `lead/lag/diff/shift` of series (esp. timeseries) in Python/ pandas/ R/ Matlab/ etc.), not [bit-shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-shift)/[bit-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-field).

See my taxonomy at [**Disambiguate the [shift] tag, it's totally overloaded**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368057/disambiguate-the-shift-tag-its-totally-overloaded), where I enumerated different meanings of "shift" on SO and came up with **at least eight**. Let's first capture all the main meanings, then discuss which do/don't need a tag, or are covered by existing tags. I suggest we move the discussion to there.