# Disambiguate the [shift] tag, it's totally overloaded

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

What are all the possible meanings of [shift], which ones deserve tags/ are synonymous with existing tags, and what should those tag names be?

1. "usage of the right and/or left shift key on the keyboard" (current tag definition, but painfully wrong for 99.9% of questions). I don't think most of us care what happens to these, as long as they don't stay under the generically-named [shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shift). Probably should have no tag name, perhaps should be moved to **"shift-key"**.
2. **Series operations spanning multiple indices e.g. lead/lag/diff/shift of series (esp. timeseries)** in Python/pandas/R/Matlab/etc. (TBD whether that's synonymous with [vectorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vectorization), but certainly new users will never think of that e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50383444/revisions))
3. **shifting of (function/shell) arguments, as in shell and PERL's** `shift()`,`pop()` keywords
4. **bit-shift operators (typically `<<`, `>>` in most languages), bit-fields, bitmasks, and related algorithms**, such as fast integer multiplication and division etc. Currently use [bit-fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-fields),[bit-shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-shift) etc.
5. **compiler and CPU questions on shift**, both arithmetic-shift (signed and unsigned) and logical-shift (circular and non-circular). Are these essentially the same as 4.? Or should we distinguish between high-level language operators and the assembly instructions they map to? Currently not much consistency in tagging, some [compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler),[vhdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vhdl) etc.
6. **SR (shift-reduce) parser** (currently only has one tag [shift-reduce-conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shift-reduce-conflict), but that's not general enough for SR parser-related stuff. Do we need [shift-reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shift-reduce)/[shift-reduce-parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shift-reduce-parser)? Can't use [parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parser), it has 734K hits and mostly to do with using parsers rather than constructing them.)
7. **editor/IDE shifting as in "block indentation", "formatting"**, "autoformatting", etc. Tagging on this is nearly nonexistent.
8. questions/answers with **hotkey/ key combinations** like Ctrl-Shift-F . Again, don't want these cluttering the generically-named [shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shift). Probably should not have any tag name (or else [hotkey-combinations]). Wherever they go, just not [shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shift).
9. "shift" as in filters, kernels, convolutions... various 1D or 2D analogs of meaning 2.?
10. there are surely yet other meanings?

And last:

- Is [shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shift) such an overloaded and confused tag name it should not be used (but rather than deleted, keep it with a tag excerpt which is a disambiguation list, something similar to the above?)

Comment: I think if you need something to be done, you'll need to create a specific request based on results of discussion here. Otherwise it will be just sharing opinions and no action IMO.

Comment: @VadimKotov: the first step is we develop consensus, the second step is we take actions. Which of the meanings listed above IYO do/do not need a tag/ fall under an existing tag, and what should those tag names be? Please write an answer

Comment: A [shift]y tag...

Comment: [shift] happens

Answer (score 20):

**TL;DR**

Yes, we should disambiguate [shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shift), but don't overly complicate things. Let's have at most [bit-shifting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-shifting), [arithmetic-shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic-shift), [logical-shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logical-shift) and [shift-reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shift-reduce) and get rid of [shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shift)

---

In detail:

1. If we have **"shift-key"**, we'll end up having **f1-key**, **f2-key** etc.;
2. **"shift"** *keywords* shouldn't exist either, otherwise in time we'll end up having a tag for each keyword of each programming language and which will need disambiguation of their own (**"javascript-var"**, **"c#-var"**, **"php-var"**);
3. **bit-shift** yes, but I'd name it **bit-shifting**, as it's an operation, and should be phrased as such
4. **arithmetic-shift** and **logical-shift** make sense
5. **shift-reduce** should include both the parser and the conflict related questions
6. We should not have tags for **IDE shifting**, as problems related to that are barely on topic for SO. In very rare cases "whitespace dependent" languages (like python) might make use of such a tag, but it's just not worth it.
7. Specific **hotkeys combinations** shouldn't have their own tags either. Imagine the possibilities :)
8. *"shift" as in filters, kernels, convolutions...*  as it's written is already ambiguous - so doesn't make sense.

Comment: You've ignored 2. Series operations spanning multiple indices e.g. lead/lag/diff/shift of series (esp. timeseries). What would you do with that? It's the one I personally care about the most. I'm not sure that [tag:vectorization] is synonymous, and not easily findable.

Comment: 7. I never said **specific** hotkey combinations should each get their own tags, that would be nuts. Clearly I suggested [hotkey-combinations] was a possible tag. Again, to disambiguate the total mess in [shift].

Comment: I actually don't know much about lead/lag/diff/shift topic so I don't know what wording would fit for that but if it involves *shift* keyword it should certainly be something like *shift-something*

Comment: 2. [argument-shifting] seems to me the self-evident name. Do not confuse keywords with the name of the topic. They could be two different things., and in fact in most of these meanings they are. Again I never said there should be a tag named after each keyword.

Comment: `lead/lag/diff/shift` are the keywords used in Series operations spanning multiple indices (esp. timeseries), in Python/pandas/R/Matlab/etc. There is currently no umbrella topic name, although as I said [tag:vectorization] is possible, although new users won't find it, so wiki would need a line explaining. No that absolutely should not be called [shift-something], noone would draw the connection. Maybe we use [tag:vectorization] or maybe we find an alternative name, or maybe we don't have an umbrella name.

Comment: "otherwise in time we'll end up having a tag for each keyword of each programming language"... [tag:foreach], [tag:for-in], [tag:for], [tag:while], should I continue?

Answer (score 3):

We should definitely do something with it

In more than 700 questions with the tag [shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shift), **very few** are actually about the physical <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. I've edited a few questions to remove the tag but there are still hundreds of them. I've given up and was writing a meta question about it until I saw this question.

Most of the remaining questions are about [bit-shifting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-shifting) or shifting elements in arrays/matrices/vectors... At this moment there are 91 questions in the tag with the word "keyboard", along with some others using "key".

I don't know why the tag exists at the first place. I think questions about those keys should use the [modifier-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modifier-key) tag. As you can see there are also the tag for [ctrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ctrl) key but for <kbd>Alt</kbd> you have to use [alt-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alt-key) since [alt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alt) is a different thing. That adds to all the inconsistencies in the naming scheme. There are also [windows-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-key) and [meta-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta-key) that has not many questions just like [alt-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alt-key).

My suggestions:

- Retag those few questions that use the tag "correctly" as [shift-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shift-key)
- Merge all those `X-key` tags to [modifier-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modifier-key), since they're generally not necessary, and only the [ctrl-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ctrl-key) have significant number of questions
- Or just remove the [shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shift) tag completely